Proposition: $\subsetneq $ is a strict partial order on $\wp (X)$.
I have proved that $(\wp (X),\subset)$ is a poset, so I am now trying to see if this proposition is true.
Proposition. Let $ \wp (X) $ be the power set of a set $ X $. Then $ (\wp (X),\subsetneq) $ is a sposet.
Proof that $\subsetneq$ is irreflexive and asymmetric. We need to prove that $ \subsetneq $ is irreflexive, transitive and asymmetric. Let $ R,S,T\in \wp(X) $ throughout.
Let $S= S$ and, aiming for a contradiction, suppose $S\subsetneq S$. Then $S\subset S$ and $S\neq S$, contradicting the initial assumption that $S=S$. Therefore not $S\subsetneq S$. Equivalently $\subsetneq $ is irreflexive.
Aiming for a contradiction, suppose both $ S\subsetneq T $ and $ T\subsetneq S $. Then $ S\neq T $ and both $ S\subset T $ and $ T\subset S $. Equivalently, $ S\neq T $ and $ S=T $. This is a contradiction. Therefore not $ S\subsetneq T $ and $ T\subsetneq S $. Equivalently, $ S\subsetneq T $ implies not $ T\subsetneq S $, and $ \subsetneq $ is asymmetric.
The proof is straightforward so far. However I ran into a problem when trying to prove that $\subsetneq$ is transitive:
$$ x\subsetneq y\subsetneq z \iff (x\subset z)\land x\neq y \land y\neq z $$
$\neq $ is not transitive (counterexample: $x=z,y\neq z$). So it does not follow from $x\neq y$ and $y\neq z$ that $x\neq z$ . So I cannot see clearly how I can derive that $x\subsetneq z$, since that requires $x\neq z$.
Then, is the proposition false, and if so roughly how could I disprove it?

Consider from the definition of $\subsetneq$ what the expression $X \subsetneq Y$ means in terms of any elements of $X$ and of $Y$.

This is actually an example of something that's true in much greater generality - if $(S \le)$ is a partial order, then $(S, <)$ is a strict partial order (where $x < y$ means $x \le y$ and $x \ne y$). This indicates that it should be possible to finish your proof without "knowing" anything about $\mathcal P(X)$ besides that it's a partial order. Indeed, in general if $x < y < z$, then we get $x \le z$ from transitivity of $\le$. If $x = z$, then we have $z \le y \le z$, implying $y = z$ by antisymmetry of $\le$, which contradicts $y < z$. So $x \ne z$, ie $x < z$.

@IzaakvanDongen "Let $ \preceq $ be a partial order on a set $ S $. Then the relation $ \prec := \preceq \setminus {(x,x):x\in S} $ is a strict partial order on $ S $." In our case let $S=\mathcal{P}(X)$, $\preceq = \subset$ and $\prec =\subsetneq$. Like this perhaps?

Yes(?). I'm not sure what your question is. What you write in quotes is true, and it does indeed apply to this case to prove this proposition instantly. If what you wrote in quotes is a theorem you have available to you, then that's all you needed to say to prove this proposition. If it's not available, then you'd have to prove it using arguments like the one in my comment and the ones in your post.

Sorry that my comment wasn't clear. I am interested in the general case you explained and I was only outlining a way that I might prove the proposition in my question using that theorem. The fact that I phrased it as a question is due to clumsiness on my part (amd I didn't explain myself sufficiently), I was essentially just showing what I had concluded from your comment. I will prove the general theorem and attach the theorem about $\mathcal{P} (X)$ as a ready consequence of it. Thanks for the guidance.

Since $X\subsetneq Y$ and $Y\subsetneq Z$, in particular we have $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset Z$, so by the transitivity of $\subset$ we get $X\subset Z$.
To prove the inclusion is strict, notice that, as $X\subsetneq Y$, there is some $y\in Y$ such that $y\notin X$. As $Y\subset Z$, we have that $y\in Z$. This means that there is an element in $Z$ that is not in $X$, which implies that $X\subsetneq Z$.

Brilliant. I feel silly now.

@WillFitchet Happens to all of us.

Theorem. Let $ \mathcal{R} $ be a partial ordering on a set $ X $. Then the reflexive reduction $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq}:=\mathcal{R} \setminus \Delta_X $ is a strict partial ordering on $ X $.
Proof. Sufficient conditions are that $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ is irreflexive, transitive and asymmetric. Let $ x,y,z \in X $ throughout and recall that $ \Delta_X :=\{(x,x)\in X^{2}\} $.
$ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ is irreflexive iff $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} \cap \Delta_X= ( \mathcal{R} \setminus \Delta_X)\cap \Delta_X =\varnothing $. If $ (x,y)\in \mathcal{R} ^{\neq} \cap \Delta_X $ then both $ (x,y)\notin \Delta_X $ and $ (x,y)\in \Delta_X $ in particular. There does not exist such a pair, and we conclude $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ is irreflexive.
We prove asymmetry of $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ first, since this makes proving transitivity easier. Suppose $ x \mathcal{R}^{\neq} y $ and $ y \mathcal{R}^{\neq} x $. Irreflexivity of $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ implies $ x\neq y $ and by definition we have $ x \mathcal{R} y $ and $ y \mathcal{R} x $. Antisymmetry of $ \mathcal{R} $ implies $ x=y $ also. This is a contradiction, and we conclude not both $ x \mathcal{R}^{\neq} y $ and $ y \mathcal{R}^{\neq} x $. Equivalently, we have $ x \mathcal{R}^{\neq} y $ implies not $ y \mathcal{R}^{\neq} x $ and $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ is asymmetric.
Suppose $ x \mathcal{R}^{\neq} y $ and $ y \mathcal{R}^{\neq} z $. Asymmetry of $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ implies both $ x\neq y $ and $ y\neq z $ and transitivity of $ \mathcal{R} $ implies $ x \mathcal{R} z $. We have two cases to investigate:

Suppose $ x\neq z $. Then $ x \mathcal{R}^{\neq} z $ by definition.
Suppose $ x=z $. Then $ x \mathcal{R}^{\neq} y $ and $ y \mathcal{R}^{\neq} x $, which contradicts asymmetry of $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $. Thus never $ x=z $.

Then $ \mathcal{R}^{\neq} $ is transitive and a strict partial ordering on $ X $. $\blacksquare$
Theorem. Inclusion, $ \subset $, is a partial ordering on every power set $ \wp (X) $.
Proof. We need to show that $ \subset $ is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric. Let $ R,S,T\in \wp (X) $ throughout.
$ S=T $ iff $ S\subset T $ and $ T\subset S $. Since for all $ S\in \wp (X) $ we have $ S=S $ it follows that in particular we have $ S\subset S $. Equivalently $ \subset $ is reflexive.
Let $ R\subset S $ and $ S\subset T $. Equivalently $ x\in R $ implies $ x\in S $ and $ x\in S $ implies $ x\in T $. It follows that in particular $ x\in R $ implies $ x\in T $. Equivalently $ R\subset T $ and $ \subset $ is transitive.
Using biconditional introduction, $ S\subset T $ and $ T\subset S $ iff $ S=T $. Therefore $ \subset $ is antisymmetric.
Thus $ \subset $ is  a partial ordering on $ \wp (X) $. $\blacksquare$
Corollary. Proper inclusion, $\subsetneq$, is a strict partial ordering on every power set $\wp (X)$.
